# How can I cleanly include Ruby code to be written to git's post-commit hook within C code?

Tags: c, ruby

I have some C code which writes Ruby code into Git's post-commit hook. The way this is currently being pulled off is by embedding the Ruby code directly in a C string like so...

```
    char * post_commit_hook = <<Ruby code here>>
```

It's then written directly to .git/hooks/post-commit by way of fprintf.

This is somewhat ugly and difficult to maintain IMO, and I was wondering if there was some way to move the Ruby code into its own file. I tried looking for ways to have GNU make to do text replacement on the fly, but somehow that still feels like a hack. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code into its own file and generate a C header from that via `make` and a scripting language of your choice.

For example, the following `make` rule

```
hook.h : hook.rb
    ./rb2h POST_COMMIT_HOOK < $< > $@
```

together with this Perl script `rb2h`

```
#!perl -w
print "#define $ARGV[0] \\\n";
chomp, s/\\/\\\\/g, s/"/\\"/g, print "\t\"$_\" \\\n" for <STDIN>;
print "\t\"\"\n"
```

will generate a file `hook.h` which defines the macro `POST_COMMIT_HOOK` containing your code.